# On flexdashboard, leafgl points are invisible until we pan or zoom

Tags: r, leaflet, flexdashboard

Upon load, WebGL points are invisible until we pan or zoom. How can I make them visible immediately on load?

Upon load no points appear:

[image]

After pan or zoom points appear:

[image]

The code below can be pasted into an Rmd and knit:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=TRUE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(leafgl)
library(sf)

n = 100

df1 = data.frame(id = 1:n,
                 x = rnorm(n, 10, 3),
                 y = rnorm(n, 49, 1.8))

pts = st_as_sf(df1, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>%
  addGlPoints(data = pts, group = "pts") %>%
  setView(lng = 10.5, lat = 49.5, zoom = 6)
```
````

Finally, my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sf_1.0-4            leafgl_0.1.1       
[3] leaflet_2.0.4.1     flexdashboard_0.5.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7         compiler_4.1.0    
 [3] pillar_1.6.4       class_7.3-19      
 [5] tools_4.1.0        digest_0.6.28     
 [7] tibble_3.1.6       jsonlite_1.7.2    
 [9] evaluate_0.14      lifecycle_1.0.1   
[11] pkgconfig_2.0.3    rlang_0.4.12      
[13] DBI_1.1.1          crosstalk_1.2.0   
[15] xfun_0.28          fastmap_1.1.0     
[17] e1071_1.7-9        dplyr_1.0.7       
[19] knitr_1.36         generics_0.1.1    
[21] htmlwidgets_1.5.4  vctrs_0.3.8       
[23] tidyselect_1.1.1   classInt_0.4-3    
[25] grid_4.1.0         glue_1.5.0        
[27] R6_2.5.1           fansi_0.5.0       
[29] rmarkdown_2.11     purrr_0.3.4       
[31] magrittr_2.0.1     htmltools_0.5.2   
[33] ellipsis_0.3.2     units_0.7-2       
[35] assertthat_0.2.1   KernSmooth_2.23-20
[37] utf8_1.2.2         proxy_0.4-26      
[39] crayon_1.4.2
```

Comment: It does seem a flexdashboard issue; when I open in my browser the points flash up but then disappear as the page resizes quickly to fill the screen. (don't see the issue when opening an html using `htmlwidgets::saveWidget(map, "test.html"); browseURL("test.html")`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been commented, There seems to be an issue with flexdashboard in R 4.1. It does work (on MacOS) with R 3.6. I'd suggest filing an issue on their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues).

Besides downgrading R, you could also "automatically" zoom in at the beginning and use `flyTo()` instead of `setView()`.

Both solutions are rather hot fixes but I am afraid that the core problem must be fixed by flexdashboard itself.

Comment: Amazing. I didn't know about `flyTo()` but it solves the issue raised in the OP. I'll let Tim know, who was looking into this from the `leafgl` side of things. Thanks!